# Javascript regex all matches

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to find a couple things in my source through regex, but I can't get it to returns all the data I need. The regex I use I've tested it on [regex101](http://regex101.com) and works just fine I think.

My source:

```
/**
 * @author person1
 * @author person2
 */

console.log('a');
```

What I want is to retrieve person1 and person2.

My code:

```
fs.readdir('./src', function (err, files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
            var file = files[i];

            fs.readFile('./src/' + file, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;

                var matches = (/@author (.*)$/gm).exec(data);
                console.log(matches);
            });
        }
    });
```

When ran this only returns person1 not person2. Is my regex wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: You should check and make sure `@author` is what you expect it to be. It could just stay `"person1"`.

Comment: [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) should be called in a loop.

Comment: @Hacketo Damn I didn't know! I thought it returned all matches! Thanks bro solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RegExp object is stateful, and retains the index of the latest match, to continue from there. Thus, you may want to run the regex several times in a loop.

```
var match, authors = [];
var r = /@author (.*)$/gm;
while(match = r.exec(data)) {
        authors.push(match[1]);
}
```

You can also use `data.match(...)`, but this won't extract the match groups.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct! In a few you get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Now a days you can use [`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

```js
const s = `
/**
 * @author person1
 * @author person2
 */

console.log('a');
`;
const re = /@author\s+(.*)$/gm;
const people = [...s.matchAll(re)].map(m => m[1]);
console.log(people);
```